# Merge two lists in Excel in ascending order

Tags: excel, list, sorting, excel-formula, merge

I have two independent lists in Excel. I need to combine them into one list and have that list sorted ascending.

For example how to merge these two lists (Named ranges `List1` and `List2` in Excel)

```
List1      List2
AA         BB
DD         CC
FF         EE
GG
```

into one list

```
AA
BB
CC
DD
EE
FF
GG
```

Can the sorted merged list be achieved using formulas only (no VBA)?

Comment: This article might be useful to you - https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/29/merge-two-columns-into-one-list-in-excel/

Comment: @coops Thanks, but unfortunately that article only works when the data in the second list is already sorted after the data in the first list, so it's really just appending the two lists. I need to append AND sort simultaneously.

Comment: It can probably be done using complex formulas and/or helper columns, but It would be easier to do using Power Query or VBA.

Comment: My vote is for Power Query, but in case you need to do this with a Pivot Table: https://www.bookkempt.com/2018/02/aligning-non-contiguous-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better/shorter formula out there but you could use:

[image]

In cell `C2` use formula:

```
=CONCAT(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$B$5,"<="&$A$2:$B$5)=SMALL(COUNTIF($A$2:$B$5,"<="&$A$2:$B$5),ROW(A1)+COUNTBLANK($A$2:$B$5)),$A$2:$B$5,""))
```

Enter as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down...

Comment: What am I doing wrong (this time)? ![Screenshot of Excel with error](http://storagemadeeasy.com/files/1606e9c59b8b1e5c5dc58b6377d06bb6.png).

Comment: You probably using an older version of Excel. Concat is available from 2016 onwards. Using concatenate won't work I'm afraid, since concat is it's replacement and can accept ranges to join (which I did in this example)

Comment: Yes, Office Professional Pro 2013. :-(

Comment: @Michael, if this is something you do from home, it might be beneficial to upgrade (won't be that costly). I guess it's not just a once of (hence why you need formulas)?

Comment: So I upgraded. And this code works perfectly on the example data. Sadly I actually need it to sort dates (dynamically) and it just seems to append them all together.

Comment: Shame, unlucky :(